# Mscorlib not referenced in Asp.Net 5 Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I am trying to port a library to ASP.NET CORE but am struggleing to get Visual Studio referencing all important parts. I noticed that the mscorlib is only added to the references under ASP.NET 5.0 but not under ASP.NET CORE. Under both frameworks i am not getting base types like System.Object even when mscorelib is referenced under ASP.NET 5.0

At first I worked with beta2 but then I build my own CoreCLR and installed it on my machine with kvm.

Kvm list shows the following:

```
Active Version           Runtime Architecture Location                      Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------                      -----
       1.0.0-beta4-11037 clr     x64          C:\Users\SomeName\.k\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta4-11037 clr     x86          C:\Users\SomeName\.k\runtimes
  *    1.0.0-beta4-11037 coreclr x64          C:\Users\SomeName\.k\runtimes default
       1.0.0-beta4-11037 coreclr x86          C:\Users\SomeName\.k\runtimes
```

When I try to debug my project in visual studio it only works under beta2 but not under my custom build. So i have to run my project manually with:

```
k run -r CoreCLR -X64
```

And everything runs just fine.

I can debug that running project within Visual Studio by attatching the debugger to it but thats not a good experience. Sure this is beta state but maybe something is wrong with my setup and someone could help me.

project.json

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"dependencies": {
     "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel": "1.0.0-beta4-1083",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4-10837",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Xml": "1.0.0-beta4-10837",
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22613",
    "System.Collections.Concurrent": "4.0.10-beta-22613",
    "System.Collections.NonGeneric": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Collections.Specialized": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.ComponentModel": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.0.10-beta-22613",
    "System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync": "4.0.10-beta-22613",
    "System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Diagnostics.Tools": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Diagnostics.TraceSource": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Dynamic.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-22613",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Linq.Expressions": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.ObjectModel": "4.0.10-beta-22613",
    "System.Reflection": "4.0.10-beta-22613",
    "System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Reflection.Extensions": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Reflection.Primitives": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22613",
    "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.0.10-beta-22613",
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Json": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml": "4.0.10-beta-22613",
    "System.Security.AccessControl": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Security.Claims": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Security.Principal": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Security.Principal.Windows": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Text.RegularExpressions": "4.0.10-beta-22613",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-22613",
    "System.Threading.AccessControl": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Threading.Tasks": "4.0.10-beta-22613",
    "System.Threading.Thread": "4.0.0-beta-22613",
    "System.Threading.ThreadPool": "4.0.10-beta-22613"
},
"frameworks": {
     "aspnet50": {
        "dependencies": {
        }
    },
    "aspnetcore50": {
        "dependencies": {
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**
I noticed that Visual Studio isnt loading the proper packages even when its showing the refreshing so I updated everything like that:

```
kpm restore
```

That improved everything by a lot. But still I cant run it properly in Visual Studio because I get a type load exception when System.Threading is loaded.
Running it manually is still no problem.

Looks like I have to wait until the next version of Visual Studio comes out to get a better experience.

I would love to know where I get the source code of System.Runtime to check whats implemented in ASPNETCORE50.

Comment: Mscorlib only exists for Desktop CLR (`aspnet50`). In CoreCLR (`aspnetcore50`), it has been split in many small packages like `System.Runtime` and `System.Threading`. What do you mean by "only works under beta2 but not under my custom build"? Do you get an error?

Comment: In response to your question if i get any errors. Visual Studio is telling me i have to install my runtime version first before using it. But when its not installed why can I use it with k run just fine? I am using the dev version of kvm btw if that helps.

Comment: Ah... Between Beta2 and Beta4, the folder structure changed. The public version of VS doesn't understand the latest runtime. Sorry, there is nothing you can do until an updated VS tooling comes. If you use VS, please use Beta2 for now.

Comment: Thank you very much now I see why Visual Studio complains.

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci do you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between Beta2 and Beta4, the folder structure changed. The public version of VS doesn't understand the latest runtime. Sorry, there is nothing you can do until an updated VS tooling comes. If you use VS, please keep using Beta2 for now.